# AWS timestream : Name already exists in dimension for the given multi measure name, or name exists in multi measures for the given dimension name

Tags: amazon-web-services, time-series, amazon-timestream

I am developing an IOT application that is writing to AWS Timestream quite frequently. It is trying to insert the records with different times but still, I am getting the same error. Each record row looks as follows

```
record = {
'Dimensions': [{'Name': 'id', 'Value': "'123'"}, 
               {'Name': 'kafkaTimestamp', 'Value': "'1657541700943'"}],
'MeasureName': 'Telemetry', 
'MeasureValueType': 'MULTI', 
'MeasureValues': [
                {'Name': 'property', 'Value': 'connection', 'Type': 'VARCHAR'}, 
                {'Name': 'value', 'Value': 'yes', 'Type': 'VARCHAR'}],
'Time': str(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
}
```

It has a couple of dimensions which remains the same, but we have different measure values each time.

My understanding is that dimensions, measure name and time make a primary key, so in the code, I am using the latest time every time I am inserting a record into the database but still records are being rejected with the exception.

`Name already exists in dimension for the given multi measure name, or name exists in multi measures for the given dimension name`

Any thoughts that what could be wrong here with the record schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a poorly documented constraint in Timestream.

You cannot reuse a multi measure name field that is already registered as a dimension or vice versa. Timestream doesn't allow "column name" reuse between dimensions and MVA fields.

This has been added to the naming limits doc:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/ts-limits.html#limits.naming

Comment: it seems while experimenting, I have used the same values with common attributes and then as dimensions so probably caused the issue. I have created a new table and it started working fine. Thanks

Comment: Great! Hope it goes well.